# Numerical analysis of PDE how to actually comput this newton method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics, finite-differences

I am reading the [2016 SIGGRAPH notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecffjiang/research/mpmcourse/mpmcourse.pdf) on MPM methods and I am trying to understand the part about implicit Euler updates. In particular the notes write these 2 equations:

$$h(v^{n+1}) = Mv^{n+1} - \Delta t f(x^n + \Delta t v^{n+1}) - Mv^n = 0$$
$$v^{i+1} = v^i - \bigg(\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}(v^i) \bigg)^{-1}h(v^i)$$

The first being a conservation of momentum constraint, the second being the implicit Euler update.

I understand the general idea, but I don't get what the actual computation I am supposed to do is.

i.e given a grid state $G$ having terms for velocity, pressure, mass,... how do I actually compute the per grid cell velocities of the next stage? Which calculations do I actually do?

Comment: No, the first equation is a time discretization for implicit Euler for the system $\dot x=v$, $M\dot v=f(x)$, while the second is the first Newton step starting from the initial point $v^{n+1,0}=v_n$. It would be better to start from the explicit Euler step.